# Permutation recursion C#

Tags: c#, recursion, permutation

I have this function that call itself to find all the possible combination with the array of int. The problem is that the program calculate the first combination and then, when the recursion continues, the List of combination still contains that value and i don't understand why.

```
public static void Permutation(List<int> items, int h, List<int> actualCombination)
    {
        if (h == actualCombination.Count)
        {
            results[results.Count] = actualCombination;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
            {
                actualCombination.Add(items[i]);

                List<int> temp = new List<int>(items);
                temp.Remove(items[i]);

                Permutation(temp, h, actualCombination);

            }
            return;
        }
    }
```

after that, i call the function in main. In my case the second parameter specify the combination length."Results" is a Dictionary composed by int as key and List as value that is used to save all the combination.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Permutation(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }, 3, new List<int>());



        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Eric Lippert has a nice blog about [Producing permutations](https://ericlippert.com/2013/04/15/producing-permutations-part-one/)

Comment: What is `results`?

Comment: Tim Rogers results is a Dictionary outside the function that i use to save all the combination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by copying the List before of the function add.

Comment: Great; then please close the question: accept your answer, delete the original, or whatever you feel is useful to people who search this site later.

Comment: Yes, i will accept my answer tomorrow because i can't accept it now, it says me that i need to wait about two days before accepting the answer.